# How to manage dll in xamarin if multiple shared project created and being used by multiple main project?

Tags: xamarin, dll, package

Things I am not sure how to handle.

I have multiple library projects and referenced some packages from nuget which may be the same packages used by other projects.

How do organized the nuget packages which all projects may be used so no dependencies conflict?

At the moment, if I have one package added to one project and other project which will use the former project library to do some action which may have used the same package but different version.

Is there a way to hold the packages in one project and shared across from all the projects.

P.S. Should I create a new project that reference all the necessary nuget packages, other projects will Add all libraries the former project added through 'Edit References' -> '.net Assembly'

Comment: If these library projects have too many identical references, it is recommended to integrate multiple library projects into one project and reference nuget packages in this project.

Comment: I do i handle it.. Currently i created a solution with a project contain package WindowsAzure.Storage from nuget. I can see the <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" /> but not the dll in the bin folder. I would thought adding a dll to a new project that way